# VBA code showing error 2042 for reason unsure

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable `fila` with a full line with Excel's values

The problem is when in Excel I have `#N/A`, VBA takes that value like `Error 2042`.

I cannot assign that value to `valor` **and** produce an error. Until this point  everything is ok, now I am trying to define a `On Error Goto` to go to the next iteration in the `For` loop, but I do **not** know why VBA doesn't handle the error.

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    txt = ActiveCell.Value2
    cell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2       
    fila = Range("C20:F20")

    For j = 1 To UBound(fila, 2)
        On Error GoTo Siguiente
        If Not IsEmpty(fila(1, j)) Then            
            valor = fila(1, j)
            cmd = Cells(1, j + 2).Value2
            devolver = function1(cmd, txt, cell, valor)
            arrayDevolver(p) = devolver
            p = p + 1                
        End If
Siguiente:
    Next
Loop
```

Comment: Why do you use Value2? (never heard of it)

Comment: Its more efficient that Value, because value check if the values is a data or currency types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215938%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a VBA error - so error handling won't catch it. To detect this issue use `IsError` before writing to your array

The simple code below handles the *Error 2042* problem with this test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim varIn As Variant
    [a1].FormulaR1C1 = "=NA()"
    If IsError([a1].Value2) Then
        varIn = "skip record"
    Else
        varIn = [a1].Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Its solve my problem I didnt know "error 2042" Its a differnte kind of errror.